# Blueman bluetooth manager is not starting in MX Linux 21

Tags: bluetooth, mx-linux, blueman

I am opening `blueman` Bluetooth manager however it is not opening, so is the bluetooth adapter software.

I thought that this is probably because the `blueman` service is stopped, so I ran

```
systemctl start Bluetooth.service
```

However this outputs

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system. Cannot connect to bus, host is not up.
```

By using the command `uname -a`, I'm found the kernel version to be

```
Debian 6.0.12-1~mx21+1 (2022-12-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is also a really [similar question on SuperUser][1] however it doesn't have an answer yet, and is for Kali linux.

Comment: Can you share output of ```sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service``` I think its not powered. Can you run your Bluetooth adapter e.g. *blueman-manager* first for power on your bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Thanks, @maxemilian. On both of those commands, the error is the same

Comment: @maxemilian I guess this is not only for bluetooth, this error is the same for every program e.g apache2

Comment: Oh then, I highly recommend get failed services https://serverfault.com/questions/857104/how-can-i-find-failed-systemd-services#968527 like this. There could be any problem other *systemctl* services.

Comment: @maxemilian MX Linux is a systemd-free Linux distro. `systemctl` is the systemd service control mechanism, you can't use it at all on MX Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen a Linux distro that doesn't come with systemd. So, `systemctl` is not the tool with which you can stop and start services.

MX Linux documentation on https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/bluetooth/ explains what you can do to start Bluetooth, but it seems very dated, so I'm not going to repeat it here untested (and I don't use MX Linux, so I can't test).

The real question here is why you're using a special-interest Linux distro like MX Linux whilst still trying to rely on tools like Blueman, which **need** the modern service infrastructure that systemd brings for most of their functionality, especially systemd-networkmanager for network and systemd-pipewire for audio connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but if anyone comes across it, what worked for me in MX-Linux was typing this into a terminal:

sudo rmmod btusb

sudo rmmod btintel

sudo modprobe btintel

sudo modprobe btusb